# Changing no args default case in getopts - bash

Tags: bash, getopts

Whenever I use getopts and i don't give any argument for a given flag I get the following message: `"option requires an argument -- d"`

I would like to remove this message and allow the user to retype the options using the `read` command.

Here is my case in the getopts:

```
if [ $# -lt $OPTIND ]; then
    echo "Option -d argument missing: needs 2 args"
    echo "Please enter two args: <arg1> <arg2>"
    read d_ID d_SIZE
    echo "disc $d_ID $d_SIZE" >> $FILENAME
else
    d_ID=$OPTARG
    eval d_SIZE=\$$OPTIND
    echo "disc $d_ID $d_SIZE" >> $FILENAME
fi
;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the behavior you want is a bad idea; there exist programs that take options with optional arguments, and they work nothing like what you describe. Your approach will likely confuse your users; it will make it difficult for other programs to interoperate with it; and it will limit the future extensibility of your script. (Imagine you want to add another option later on. `your_script.sh -d -e` will pass `-e` as an argument to `-d`, even if the user wanted to use `-d` with no argument and intended `-e` as a separate option.) And it's especially bizarre to expect *one* argument if it's on the command line, but *two* arguments from standard input.

That said . . .

To achieve some of the effect of an optional option-argument, you can tell `getopts` to be "silent" (that is, to use "silent error reporting") by putting a colon `:` at the beginning of the option string. (For example, instead of `getopts d: ...`, you would write `getopts :d: ...`.) Then, when an option's argument is missing, it will set the option-name to `:` (instead of `d`) and `OPTARG` to the option-name (namely `d`, instead of the option-argument).

For example, the below script can be called either as `script.sh -d foo` or as `script.sh -d`, with the latter causing the user to be prompted to type a value:

```
#!/bin/bash

if getopts :d: arg ; then
    if [[ "$arg" == d ]] ; then
        d="$OPTARG"
    else
        read -p 'Enter d: ' d
    fi
    echo "d is: $d"
else
    echo 'no d'
fi
```

Resulting in:

```
$ ./script.sh
no d

$ ./script.sh -d
Enter d: x
d is: x

$ ./script.sh -d y
d is: y
```